# suggestion for a stable Chromecasting app?

Tags: chromecast

as above.

I'm using a Galaxy S9+ running Android 10 with a recent security patch.

---

I have some videos (h.265 AMD VCE encoded using handbrake) that I can cast with no issues when using VLC on the desktop (Windows 10/macOS). The laptops are around 10-15 feet away with wooden walls in-between itself and the router.

I tried casting (6-7 feet away from the router with no walls in-between) with these 3 apps and it's very unstable (video freeze, completely stops and other random issues)

- MX Player Pro
- VLC
- Google Photos
  Thank you.

Comment: You should list out the codec parameters used for your videos. My guess is that the desktop is doing the necessary transcoding/downsampling if you aren't using a [Chromecast Ultra which has documented support for h.265](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#chromecast_ultra). See supported codecs: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#mp4_video_only If everything looks fine, you should state your Chromecast device and network (a/g/b/n/ac) as well.

Comment: I'm using the chromecast device built-in on the TV. I only selected AMD VCE on handbrake and selected "main" as profile. nothing else can be change on the video tab.

Comment: Unless your TV is 4K with Chromecast branding, I'm leaning toward the TV only supporting h.264. However if your TV is 4K with Google branding then honestly I'm not sure. h.265 AMD VCE is GPU hardware encoding, you may want to try CPU encoding or a different format (like VP9).

Comment: @MorrisonChang but I can cast fine from my desktop using the same h.265 video...

Comment: Point taken. At this point I'm not sure if the problem is with the TV or Android. One test to try the same video file with a different phone to see if the same issues show up. I still recommend updating your post with make/model of TV and what the codec worked/didn't work as shown in VLC (Media Info).